# Подвисает шторка в Navigation Drawer

Tags: java, android-studio, android-navigation-drawer

В приложении есть только один фрагмент и он выполнен правильно, но на многих моих приложениях при свайпе что бы вызвать меню навигации на этом моменте см.рис. подвисает

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Подвисает намертво? Или просто зависает и продолжает выполняться? И нужно все же увидеть код, без него никак.

Comment: Не намертво, приходится еще раз свайпануть

Comment: Внутри навигейшена есть изображение (ImageView)? Приложите xml, да и код тоже, а то гадать, в чем дело, можно очень долго.

Comment: Нету, просто чисто новый фрагмент с  timePicer